# How to add a curly close quote or apostrophe to plot text when knitting to pdf?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, typography

I am currently plotting some data from a survey question to be used in a book. It would be useful to put typographically-correct curly quotes or what are sometimes called "smart" quotes around the survey question on the x-axis.

When creating a plot in R markdown, however, it is easy to create a typographically-correct open curly quote or apostrophe with back-tics (e.g., using one or two back-tics will create a curly ‘ or “ vs straight ' or ") but it is not obvious how to add a curly close apostrophe or quote (e.g., ’ or ”). I assume the solution is simple but was unable to figure it out via options like `plotmath` and hardcoding curly quotes with something like `labs(x = '“some text”')` didn't work. Other options like `sQuote()` or `dQuote()` work interactively but, when knitting to pdf, the curly quotes get converted to straight quotes.

How can I add a curly close quote or apostrophe to plot text when knitting in R markdown to pdf?

````
---
title: "Curly Quote in Plot Example"
output: pdf_document
date: "2022-08-17"
---

```{r}

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = hp, y = mpg) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "`Is MPG related to HP?`")

```
````

[image: Plot of MPG vs HP with x-axis that includes a correct open curly quote and an incorrect close curly quote]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way we can add curly quotes on the x-axis title is by using HTML code and then render it using `element_markdown` from `{ggtext}` package.

````
---
title: "Curly Quote in Plot Example"
output:
  pdf_document:
    dev: cairo_pdf
date: "2022-08-17"
---

```{r}

library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = hp, y = mpg) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "&lsquo;Is MPG related to HP?&rsquo;")+
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_markdown()
  )

```
````

The x-axis title looks like this now,

[image: x-axis title with quote]

Comment: That's a clever solution for HTML output but on my computer for pdf output it generates lots of grid.Call.graphics warnings and the curly quotes get replaced with "..." Is your example plot from pdf output?

Comment: This should not be related to latex or pandoc, since this is handled by `ggtext` and `knitr` is just rendering the png image generated by the code chunk. Can you check, if you simply run the code chunk, do you see the quote in the code chunk output, (In my case, curly quotes are visible when I run just that ggplot code in the code chunk output)

Comment: Yes, `ggtext` installed and, yes, curly quotes appear when run both interactively and when knit to HTML (but not when knit to pdf).

Comment: @shafee This is what I get when knitting your solution: http://appliedstats.org/curly_quote_shafee.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `cairo_pdf` device. You can add `dev="cairo_pdf"` to your chunk and then use `ggtext` with `element_markdown` like this:

````
---
title: "Curly Quote in Plot Example"
output: pdf_document
date: "2022-08-17"
---

```{r, dev="cairo_pdf"}

library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = hp, y = mpg) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "&lsquo;Is MPG related to HP?&rsquo;")+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_markdown())

```
````

Output:

[image]